# Call Python web service using PHP

Tags: php, python, soap

**Python Web Service Code:**

```
import web 
from soaplib.wsgi_soap import SimpleWSGISoapApp
from soaplib.service import soapmethod
from soaplib.serializers import primitive as soap_types

urls = ("/hello", "HelloService",
        "/hello.wsdl", "HelloService",
        )
render = web.template.Template("$def with (var)\n$:var")



class SoapService(SimpleWSGISoapApp):
    """Class for webservice """
    @soapmethod(soap_types.String,_returns=soap_types.String)
    def hello(self,message):
        """ Method for webservice"""
        return "Hello world "+message



class HelloService(SoapService):
    """Class for web.py """
    def start_response(self,status, headers):
        web.ctx.status = status
        for header, value in headers:
            web.header(header, value)


    def GET(self):
        response = super(SimpleWSGISoapApp, self).__call__(web.ctx.environ, self.start_response)
        return render("\n".join(response))


    def POST(self):
        response = super(SimpleWSGISoapApp, self).__call__(web.ctx.environ, self.start_response)
        return render("\n".join(response))

app=web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

    @ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");


    $client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8080/hello.wsdl');

    echo("<pre>");
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
    echo("</pre>");
    $params = array('World');


    try {
        print_r($client->__soapCall('hello', $params));

    } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo $exception;
    }
?>
```

When I run my php code, it reports information below

> SoapFault exception: [helloFault] hello() takes exactly 2 arguments (1
>   given) in C:\website\cosmetics\src\test02.php:15 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\website\cosmetics\src\test02.php(15):
>   SoapClient->__soapCall('hello', Array) #1 {main}

How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: To look at WSDL (hello.wsdl) in this case is useful. Post it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what SoapClient is exactly, but it just looks like it needs another argument. What does the documentation say?

Comment: the documentation is referred to this link http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php I can not find any useful information in this documentation.

Comment: Could you try a var_dump() instead of echo for $exception and give us the response ?