# Consume Wsgi Python web service with php

Tags: php, python

Is there any tutorial on how can i Consume Wsgi Python web service with php ?

There is a few article on here like this:
"[Call Python web service using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190115/call-python-web-service-using-php)"
but im not using soap

here is my sample python web service :

```
import pymysql
import json 
from bottle import route, run ,request

@route('/testing/', method='GET')
def testing_request():
    testing = request.GET.get( "testing" )
    if "" != testing:
-------do something on mysql--------
-------return something to json--------

application = bottle.default_app()
```

Im using this file as Wsgi on apache web sever same location as the php web site that wants to consume it.